# Navegação em pastas no PHP

Tags: php, diretório

Tenho algumas pastas no meu projeto e preciso percorrer todas guardando o nome da pasta mãe, da filha, e de seus arquivos...

A pasta mãe é "Manual", dentro dela tenho outras pastas "Cadastro" e "Relatorios", nessas sub-pastas tenho algumas imagens (print de tela), então preciso retornar um array com os dados:

```
array[0][0] = "Manual";
array[0][1] = "Cadastro";
array[0][2] = "Imagem001.png";

array[1][0] = "Manual";
array[1][1] = "Cadastro";
array[1][2] = "Imagem002.png";

array[2][0] = "Manual";
array[2][1] = "Relatorio";
array[2][2] = "Imagem001.png";

array[3][0] = "Manual";
array[3][1] = "Relatorio";
array[3][2] = "Imagem001.png";
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? Já tentei usar o dir do php mas não consegui pegar a pasta mãe...

Comment: Tentou fazer usando um foreach() para acesso aos objetos?

Comment: @AndréBaill O foreach eu sei usar hehehe... o problema é acessar cada diretório do windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    function ListFolder($path){
        $dir_handle = opendir($path) or die("Erro");
        $dirname = end(explode("/", $path));

        echo ("<li> $dirname");
        echo "<ul>";
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                if (is_dir($path."/".$file)){
                    ListFolder($path."/".$file);
                }
                else{
                    echo "<li>$file</li>";
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";

        closedir($dir_handle);
    }
?>

ListFolder('Manual');
```

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode utilizar esse método:

```
function gerenciarArquivos($path)
    {
        $files = glob($path."*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
        $listFiles = array();

        if (count($files)) {
            $listFiles[] = "<ul>";
            foreach ($files as $file) {
              $listFiles[] = "<li>{$file}</li>";
            }
            $listFiles[] = "</ul>";
        }

        return implode("\n", $listFiles);
    }
echo gerenciarArquivos('/folder/');
```